# Get ALL the options of a multi select in jQuery, including those which are not selected

Tags: jquery, multi-select

I've seen plenty of code snippets to retrieve the selected options of a multi select in jQuery, but none of the codes I've seen to retrieve ALL the options of a multi select, including those which are not selected, worked!

What I want to do, is to put all the options in a string, separated by commas.
I have this code for elements that are selected:

```
var selectedOptions2 = $('#relationslist option:selected');
            var selectedValues2 = $.map(selectedOptions2 ,function(option) 
            {
                return option.value;
            }).join(',');
```

How can I adapt it to put in selectedValues all options, including the ones which are not selected?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get all options by using the selector `$('#relationslist option');` instead of `$('#relationslist option:selected');`

i.e.

```
var selectedOptions2 = $('#relationslist option');
...
```

Answer (score 1):

This line of code executes a selector that returns all selected options.

```
var selectedOptions2 = $('#relationslist option:selected');
```

The key part is the [`:selected`](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/) pseudo-selector, since that's what tells jQuery to only bring back the ones which are currently selected. If you want **all** options, just take that part out.

Comment: That's odd, it's the first thing I've tested and it returned null, although the multi select is filled with jQuery just before this snippet. Is that normal?

Comment: @user1881815 I'd need to see more of the code then; based purely on what you've posted just removing the `:selected` part of the selector should work.

Comment: Sorry, it works, actually. I just made a mistake in the select's name. :)

Answer (score 0):

You were really close - just remove :selected from your selector -

http://jsfiddle.net/EekQZ/1/

```
var selectedOptions2 = $('#relationslist option');             
var selectedValues2 = $.map(selectedOptions2 ,function(option) {
    return option.value;
}).join(',');
```